# Error: Argument error: username and password are required unless use_unauthenticated is set

Tags: ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I'm attempting to use STT service with the iam apikey.

If I set the IAM credentials like the [documentation shows](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text?code=node#authentication) (below) I get the error: username and password are required unless use_unauthenticated is set

```
let speech_to_text = new SpeechToTextV1({
  iam_apikey: STT_credentials.apikey,
  iam_url: STT_credentials.url
});
```

If I pass the use_anauthenticated value I get a 401 response:

```
let speech_to_text = new SpeechToTextV1({
  iam_apikey: STT_credentials.apikey,
  iam_url: STT_credentials.url,
  use_unauthenticated: true
});
```

response:

```
Error! Code:401 Type: undefined Message: Unauthorized
```

If I look at the file in the error:

```
/Users/jward/Desktop/speech_lab_assets/STT/node_mod
ules/watson-developer-cloud/lib/base_service.js:73:13
```

I see that it will throw an error if there is no username/password param:

```
if (!options.use_unauthenticated) {
    if (!options.username || !options.password) {
      throw new Error('Argument error: username and password are required unless use_unauthenticated is set');
    }
```

How am I supposed to use IAM if the username/password is a requirement of the [watson-developer-cloud](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk#iam) tooling? Is this an issue with the node module or am I doing something wrong?

I am using watson-developer-cloud@2.42.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The endpoint is specified as `url` and not `iam_url` as you have it.

This works for me -

```
const  STTV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/speech-to-text/v1');

let sttService = new STTV1({
  url: url,
  iam_apikey = apikey
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked my newest code and I am using url instead of iam_url. This doesn't make sense to me but I moved the .js file from /Users/jward/Desktop/speech_lab_assets/STT/ to /Users/jward/Desktop/speech_lab_assets/ and it runs. All of my other files in the STT directory continue to fail.

Comment: Ugh, I forgot to run npm installin the dir.